# Fetching data from facebook and rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, react-dom

i am stuck with one problem in react and cant find a solution , hope to find a help here . I have an app which fetches data from facebook and render that data in my EventDashboard component (in the method `componentDidMount` i made a fetch) . In the render method i render another component(UserAvatar) which needs a some data from fetch , but it only gets the initial data . I need to pass to that component the fetched data , not the initial one . How can i handle this problem ?

here is the gist from github [components with reducer and actions](https://gist.github.com/norayr-bp/dcbadc18d0e9ba5fdfa3065e370e8fe1)

Comment: Share the relevant parts of the code in the body of your post. It is easier to look at.